# Mongo aggregation with $ne

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I can't seem to find any resources at all on Mongo aggregation with the boolean operations. My query looks something like this (I am using the pymongo driver):

```
db.collection.aggregate([{'$match': {'foo': 3, 'bar': 'baz'}},
                          {'$project': {'quxx': 1, '_id': 0, 'count': 1}},
                          {'$group': {'total': {'$sum': '$count'}, '_id': '$quxx'}},
                          {'$sort': {'total': -1}},
                          {'$limit': 2000}])
```

Which all works great (`$match` is on an index etc). Now, there is a single rogue quxx that I would like to filter out of the pipeline so I thought that I would use the `$ne` operator. However, I can't seem to figure out the proper way to do it! I'm not sure if I'm not placing it at the right point (I want it after the `$match` operator but before the `$group` operator) or I have the syntax wrong but help would be appreciated.

The things I have tried so far (all in their own step after `$match`) are:

```
{'$quxx': {'$ne': 'rogue'}}
{'quxx': {'$ne': 'rogue'}}
{'$ne': {'quxx': 'rogue'}}
{'$ne': {'$quxx': 'rogue'}}
```

Every single one of them gives me `unrecognized pipeline op`.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41377775/how-to-compare-two-fields-in-a-document-in-pipeline-aggregation-mongodb

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You would either put that in its own `$match` pipeline element, or just include it in the initial `$match`.

So either add:

```py
{'$match': {'quxx': {'$ne': 'rogue'}}}
```

or modify the initial `$match` to:

```py
{'$match': {'foo': 3, 'bar': 'baz', 'quxx': {'$ne': 'rogue'}}}
```

Comment: The initial match traverses a composite index and I don't want to index on quxx. Does that mean I should go with the former?

Comment: @dreamriver Check the modified initial match using `explain` on an identical `find` to see if your existing index is still used (I expect it would be).

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41377775/how-to-compare-two-fields-in-a-document-in-pipeline-aggregation-mongodb